# Carry.Over: Test the Carry-over effect, how to use?

Tags: r

I'm doing a cross-over trial, and would like to in some way calculate whether there is a significant carryover effect between the treatment periods or not.

In the **TrialSize** package for R, there is the function **Carry.Over(alpha, beta, sigma1, sigma2, gamma)**, where alpha and beta is self-explanatory, but I don't really understand what the sigma1, sigma2 and gamma should be.

According to documentation:

- alpha: significance level, e.g. .95
- beta: power, e.g. .8
- sigma1: standard deviation of sequence AB
- sigma2: standard deviation of sequence BA
- gamma: the difference of carry-over effect between sequence AB and BA

So how should sigma1, sigma2 and gamma be calculated, so that I can add them into this formula?

Kind regards